# How to calculate how many can a stick hold?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy

I got two boxes, and one stick, two boxes are high enough for a human body. I put one stick between two boxes, like this:

[image]

The boxes are yellow, and the stick is brown. So, I would like to put something on the stick, but how can I know how much things I can put on the stick? Except from trial and error, is there any scientistic way to calculate it? Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to calculate the weight before the stick breaks?  Is the weight concentrated at the center, evenly spread, or what?

Comment: I think [Euler-Bernoulli beam theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Bernoulli_beam_theory#Maximum_stresses_at_a_cross-section) would be a good start.

Comment: http://www.engineersedge.com/beam_calc_menu.shtml